# Why does custom Binding not update SwiftUI TextField?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I feel like I'm misunderstanding how `Binding` works in SwiftUI, in that I do not understand why the **first** `TextField` below does not update when the `text` view model property changes:

```swift
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String = "Hello"
    
    var binding: Binding<String>!

    init() {
        binding = Binding(get: { self.text }, set: { self.text = $0 })
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = MyViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Actual: " + viewModel.text)
            TextField("Field 1", text: viewModel.binding)
            TextField("Field 2", text: $viewModel.text)
        }
    }
}

struct MyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyView()
    }
}
```

Typing in the first `TextField` always updates second one (and the `Text` label), but typing in the second `TextField` only propagates changes to the `Text` label, shown here:

[image: simulator screenshot]

In my actual use case, the list of `TextField` views is dynamically generated from a user-defined template, likewise with custom bindings to a `@Published` complex object (i.e. not as simple as a `String`) on `MyViewModel`. In my limited experience, I believe the dynamic nature of the view prevents me from coding it in a straight-forward fashion, as seen with the second `TextField`.

My guess is that SwiftUI has no insight that the custom binding should even need to be refreshed, in which case my question becomes: How can I tell the binding to "refresh" the `TextField` while also supporting dynamically-generated content?

Comment: Because `@Binding` the wrapper can trigger a `View` refresh when it is inside of a `View` `struct` but as you have written it it wouldn't trigger an update. I would even consider it unreliable inside a `class` `@Published` is really the only SwiftUI wrapper that works reliably outside of a `View`

Answer (score 2):

First, consider this line code

```
binding = Binding(get: { self.text }, set: { self.text = $0 })
```

You are assigning binding value to `self.text` by `self.text = $0`, it means now `self.text` value updated and your view is rendering with new value so, it will display with new value in the all place.

Now, you are changing the value of `@Published` var by the second field. when you are changing this var, your just changing the value of `@Published var text: String` this var and it's not related to this binding var `var binding: Binding<String>!` there is no communication or connection. so `var binding: Binding<String>!` value is not changed and remains the same as the old value.

If you want to update both directions, you also need to add this code

```
@Published var text: String = "Hello" {
        didSet {
            binding = Binding(get: { self.text }, set: { self.text = $0 }) // <-- Here
        }
    }
```

So now it will reflect on both sides.

---

If you have still confusion
Replace this line

```
var binding: Binding<String>!
```

with this

```
@Published var binding: String = ""
```

And now think. The above way is the same way as your code, just have a different declaration. These are now two different var but doing the same things.

Comment: Thank you, the "didSet" addition worked for me, however how is it then that the View picks up the new (but identical) instance of "binding"? If the View is already refreshing its copy of "binding" from the ViewModel due to the text change, then why wouldn't the original code do the same?

Comment: But in your code your view updates but not update init() of the view model. so the binding var has the same old result. in your code ``` set: { self.text = $0 }``` this part never executes when you updating the published var.

Comment: The binding is only set once, but the get/set are escaping closures which get called more than once, and they also access the latest value of "text" via "self". For example, the TextField calls the "get" again on commit. I was thinking there was a way other than the property wrapper to get it to update, but my confusion is likely just trying to apply binding techniques from other frameworks I'm experienced with.